# WIndows 10 - How to Enable Windows Defender Firewall with Forticlient installed

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall, windows-defender, forticlient

I have a remote job for which I occasionally have to use a VPN to connect to the corporate network.  My company uses FortiClient for this, and despite Fortinet's best efforts, I've managed to break some of the more invasive corporate monitoring features while keeping the VPN functionality intact (I was not successful in recreating the VPN connection with other software).  But Windows Defender Firewall is still broken.  When I try to start the service through services.msc, I get "Error 1068: Dependency Service Failed to Start".

I'm told that the only way to fix this is to uninstall the third party firewall, but that obviously isn't an option, and I frankly don't believe it.  I think there's a file or registry key somewhere that can be modified to switch the active firewall to Windows Defender Firewall.  I don't mind if FortiClient's antivirus, web filtering and logging features no longer work, as I've already done quite a bit to cripple these myself.

Comment: You're not wrong, but they didn't know.  Microsoft lists "Uninstalling any third party antivirus" as a solution to this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.  This is an extremely niche problem, but here's the solution anyway.

First, make sure that all dependencies of the Windows Defender Firewall service are running.  Check dependencies under **Properties** in services.msc.

In my case, Base Filtering Engine wasn't running, and I couldn't start it.  I solved this by going to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE** in the registry, adding **NT SERVICE\BFE** in the "Group or user names" list and giving it special permissions as well as all additional permissions under "Advanced."

Link to the tutorial I followed: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-base-filtering-engine-service-startup-problems/

Second, I had to restore some registry permissions to get Windows Defender Firewall itself started.  I followed this tutorial: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-windows-could-not-start-the-windows-firewall-on-local-computer

In case that link is broken, here are the steps:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Epoch  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dhcp
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dhcp\Configurations

For each of the above registry keys, insert **NT SERVICE\mpssvc** as a new user, granting "Full control."